# Laravel display the query parameter in the url

Tags: php, laravel

I have users table and each user have a column for 'qr_url' and it's a random 170 characters length string generated with Str::random
I have a page that displays all the users and for each user there is a button named inquiry to check if the user exists in the database
I have a route name inquiry that check if this qr_url already for a user or not

```
Route::get('/users/inquiry/{query}', [UserController::class, 'inquiry'])->name('users.inquiry');
```

in the inquiry() function I receive this query that contain the qr_url

```
public function inquiry($query)
{
    $user = User::where('qr_url', '=', $query)->first();

    return view('users/inquiry', compact('user'));
}
```

I need to know how can I make the URL looks like that

```
http://example.com/Home/GetResultByQR?query=theqr_url
```

Comment: Where do you generate that url, please include that code

Answer (score 0):

Hello guy you should use `request()->get('query')`. For example:

```
public function inquiry()
{
    $user = User::where('qr_url', '=', request()->get('query'))->first();

    return view('users/inquiry', compact('user'));
}
```

Comment: this gets the user and works well but still not changing the URL like i want

Comment: You can use [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-resolution-logic) Like: `Route::bind('query', function ($value) {return request()->get('query'); }); `